# How to translate this Javascript snippet to C#

Tags: javascript, c#

Javascript:

```
function bounds(a, b, c) {
  null != b && (a = Math.max(a, b));
  null != c && (a = Math.min(a, c));
  return a
}
```

Honestly, I don't even understand what is going on here.  If `b` isn't null, then `a` gets set `Math.max(a, b)`.  if `c` isn't null, `a` gets set from `Math.min(a, c)`?

How does one translate this to C#?

P.S.  This is my translation.  Is this correct?

```
private double bounds(double a, double? b, double? c) {
    if (b != null) a = Math.Max(a, b.Value);
    if (c != null) a = Math.Min(a, c.Value);

    return a;
}
```

Comment: Your statement "I don't even understand what is going on here" tells you what the first step should be. **Understand what is going on**. Once you understand what the program is *for*, then ask yourself "how would I implement those semantics in C#?"  Start *that* process by deciding what the signature of the method is. But certainly do not do an expression-for-expression translation of this hard-to-understand mess.

Comment: Your translation is not correct.

Comment: While you are rewriting this, question *every* decision that you're making *with an eye to improving the readability of the code*.  Why are the names of the variables `a`, `b` and `c`, instead of what they *mean* in the program?  Why is variable `a` being overwritten, instead of a *new* local variable with a *new, meaningful name* being created? Locals are cheap; use them!  And so on.

Comment: @EricLippert What about the translation is incorrect?  Parameter names notwithstanding.

Comment: A valuable skill that you should work on developing today is **reading the code you just wrote.**  Read the code you wrote, not the code you think you wrote. You'll see the mistake.

Comment: Frankly what I would do, were I tasked with porting this code to C# is to understand the code by looking at how it is used at call sites, because frankly it is not making a whole lot of sense to me.  This code is like a master class in how to design a tiny, trivial method that resists understanding. Again, understand the *purpose* of this thing, and then implement sensible, clear, testable code that implements that purpose.

Comment: the javascipt has Max and Min, but you used Max & max in your C#

Comment: What I'm getting at is that it *appears* that the contract of the method -- ignoring the null checks for the moment -- is "if `c` is the smallest of `a`, `b`, and `c` then return `c`, otherwise return whichever of `a`, `b`, and `c` is the one *between* the other two."  Why is that contract something you'd want to implement? I don't know.  That's why you should look at the call sites; that will give you a hint as to the true meaning. Maybe `c` is never the smallest, for instance, and this code is supposed to return the middle element but the bug is never being caught.

Comment: @EricLippert This snippet of code is at the bottom of a long stack of mathematical methods, full of Sin, Tan, ATan, etc..., that are of the same hard to understand quality.  It's hard to see at a glance what each method does.  My purpose in porting it to C# is to feed it some data and understand how it behaves.

Comment: Well if that is the typical quality of the code, you are in for a hard slog. Hopefully there is some documentation somewhere that indicates what algorithm the code is ultimately attempting to implement.

Comment: @AngryHacker: I wonder if this sort of question would be well-suited towards codereview.  While this question indicates less confidence in correctness than is ideal for a CR question, that could easily be corrected by being more confident in your code (e.g., running some basic test cases yourself before asking for review would have prevented the Math.Max/Math.Min switch).  I recommend https://www.linqpad.net/ as a simple test scratchpad.

Comment: @Brian: This sort of question is ill-suited to the code review site. The code review site is for code that *does what it is supposed to do but could be better*.  The problem here is that we don't even know what the code is supposed to do, so it is hard to say whether it is correct. I've tried to indicate in my answer how I would approach improving the code, but it relies upon us making a good guess as to the meaning of the code.

Comment: @EricLippert: I realize that.  That is why I said that he shouldn't post it to CR until he was more confident in his code's correctness.

Answer (score 10):

> Honestly, I don't even understand what is going on here.

Me neither. The code appears to implement the contract "if `c` is the least element, return it, and otherwise, return the middle element of `a`, `b`, and `c`, plus some nullability checks of unknown purpose.

This is a bizarre contract to implement and it makes me think that it might be an untested implementation of "return the middle element" that has a bug; if `c` is in practice never the smallest element, perhaps the bug is never caught.

> How does one translate this to C#?

Understand the meaning of the code in context, and then implement those semantics in idiomatic C#.  It's the understanding that is the important part; once you understand the code, writing a correct, testable implementation will be straightforward.

> This is my translation. Is this correct?

```
private double bounds(double a, double? b, double? c) {
  if (b != null) a = Math.Max(a, b.Value);
  if (c != null) a = Math.Min(a, c.Value);
  return a;
}
```

It is correct in that it accurately implements the semantics of the original, possibly-buggy code. But it is hardly better. Let's improve it. Three things stand out:

- The method does not consume `this`, so it should be `static`.
- The method is a C# method and should follow the naming conventions of C#.
- Methods that overwrite their formals are hard to read at design time, and hard to debug at run time. For that matter, any method that mutates a variable is harder to understand than a method that does not mutate a variable.
- Variables named `a`, `b`, `c`, that have meanings to them are hard to read because they obscure those meanings.

Let's fix all of them.

```
private static double Bounds(double a, double? b, double? c) 
{
  double larger = (b == null) ? a : Math.Max(a, b.Value);
  double smaller = (c == null) ? larger : Math.Min(larger, c.Value);
  return smaller;
}
```

We still do not have good names for `a`, `b` and `c`, but at least we know that `larger` and `smaller` reflect their meanings.

Are we done?  Always ask yourself **how can I make this simpler**?

You can make it simpler by moving the checks into a helper.

```
private static double Max(double x, double? y) =>
  (y == null) ? x : Math.Max(x, y.Value)

private static double Min(double x, double? y) =>
  (y == null) ? x : Math.Min(x, y.Value)
```

And now our method becomes:

```
private static double Bounds(double a, double? b, double? c) 
{
  double larger = Max(a, b);
  double smaller = Min(larger, c);
  return smaller;
}
```

And now we realize that we can rewrite this as

```
private static double Bounds(double a, double? b, double? c) => 
  Min(Max(a, b), c);
```

It is certainly still not clear what the *purpose* of this thing is, but I hope you agree that my implementation could not be more clear in its action. In my implementation it is dead obvious that the semantics are "if `c` is the least, return it, otherwise return the middle element". Compare the understandability of my version to the original godawful mess and see which one is easier to understand.

**What is the lesson here?**

- Organize the code into single-assignment form
- Move complex logic into helper methods that abstract it away
- Rewrite the code to eliminate unnecessary explanatory variables.
- The code becomes clean and easy to comprehend.

---

Further musings; suppose that my conjecture is right, and the intention is to write:

```
private static double Middle(double test, double? bottom, double? top)
```

The semantics of the method are:

- `bottom` and `top` may both be null.
- If both are non-null then `bottom` must be the smaller.
- If `bottom` and `top` are both not null then the value in the middle is returned.
- If `bottom` and `top` are both null then `test` is the value in the middle.
- If `bottom` is null but `top` is non null, then the smaller of `test` and `top` is the value in the middle. Here we're treating "null" like "negative infinity" for the bottom.
- Similarly if `top` is null but `bottom` is not, then the larger of `bottom` and `test` is the middle one. Here the null top is treated like "positive infinity".

This is actually a pretty sensible contract, but it requires that we know that `bottom` be always smaller than `top` when they are not both null. A good implementation in C# would either `Debug.Assert` that fact (if the method is `private`) or `throw` if the precondition was violated (if the method is `public`).

If this is the case then the better choice would be to do this:

```
private static double Middle(double test, double? bottom, double? top) =>
  Middle(
    test, 
    bottom ?? Double.NegativeInfinity, 
    top ?? Double.PositiveInfinity);

private static double Middle(double test, double bottom, double top) =>
  Math.Min(Math.Max(test, bottom), top);
```

(If you are unfamiliar with `??`, it is read "coalesce" and `x??y` means "if `x` is not null then use `x.Value`, otherwise use `y`". It is a very useful operator.)

Again, see how nice and easy the code looks when you write it with an eye to readability. It becomes clear that "null means negative infinity on the bottom and positive infinity on the top" because that's what the code says!

Alternatively, write a correct implementation of Middle that does not require any ordering of the three inputs:

```
// True if test is between b1 and b2, false otherwise
private static bool Between(double test, double b1, double b2) =>
  ((b1 <= test) & (test <= b2)) | ((b2 <= test) & (test <= b1));

// Returns the middle value of a, b, and c.
private static double Middle(double a, double b, double c)
{
  if (Between(a, b, c) return a;
  if (Between(b, a, c) return b;
  return c;
}
```

Or, if you like

```
private static double Middle(double a, double b, double c) =>
  Between(a, b, c) ? a : Between(b, a, c) ? b : c;
```

And now we can once again write our Bounds method easily:

```
private static double Bounds(double test, double? bottom, double? top) =>
  Middle(
    test, 
    bottom ?? Double.NegativeInfinity, 
    top ?? Double.PositiveInfinity);
```

Again, think about what we are striving for here. **Simple methods that do one thing and do it extremely well**.  Once you have that, you can use those methods to build *other* simple methods, and gradually increase the complexity of the program without making it hard to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Here's roughly what that JavaScript translates to:

```
function bounds(a, b, c) {
  // If "b" not null, then update "a" as the maximum of "a" and "b" 
  null != b && (a = Math.max(a, b));

  // If "c" not null, then update "a" as the maximum of "a" and "c" 
  null != c && (a = Math.min(a, c));

  return a
}
```

A C# equalivalnt could be written as:

```
static double ? bounds(double ? a, double ? b, double ? c)
{
    if (b.HasValue)
    {
        a = a.HasValue ? Math.Max(a.Value, b.Value) : a;
    }

    if (c.HasValue)
    {
        a = a.HasValue ? Math.Min(a.Value, c.Value) : a;
    }

    return a;
}
```

Comment: How can a decimal be null?

Comment: Use decimal? instead of decimal.

Comment: For that matter, why choose `decimal`? The closest type to JavaScript's `Number` would be `double`.

Comment: Thanks, but you *really* need to address Eric Lippert's point, as well, for it to work at all.

Comment: this link: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp says that number type is Always 64-bit Floating Point. So double? is the correct type.

Comment: As a clarification, Microsoft suggests `decimal` for values specifically representing currencies (aka prices, money transactions, etc). The `?` operator is used to turn `value` types into reference types, making them nullable. Value types such as `int`, `float`, `decimal`, `double` can all use `?` to become nullable: `int? j = null;`.

Comment: The original code will return the original value passed in for a if b and c are null, not double.NaN

Comment: Your implementation is improving; now can you do one that does not mutate `a`?  Mutating a formal is a bad practice because it makes it harder to understand the program when reading it, and harder to debug it when running it.

Comment: Compare your implementation to mine; which do you think is the easier to understand?

Comment: Your solution is very easy to follow. Also, in regards to your prior comment, I agree; immutability is preferable. Also in this case, your functional expression of `bounds()`  is straight forward to follow and is a much better alternative. Wasn't too sure if adding helper functions was going "out of bounds" of what the OP wanted as far as a solution but on reflection, supplementing my answer with a solution that applied similar ideas to those you have put forward that would have been fine - great answer by the way :)